# Libreoffice Calc cell text not refreshed when edited

Tags: 16.04, xorg, libreoffice, xfce, text

When I edit a cell in Libre office Calc, it doesn't clear the old text so all the old letters are left in place, until I click or press return.

A picture tells a thousand words:

[image: in the cell above, I go to the start of the line and put in a new letter]

I'm not sure if it is because I have been messing around with my graphics drivers, and updated the kernel to 4.6, and tried the freshers libreoffice ppa with the same results.  Any ideas?

```
uname -a
Linux A 4.6.0-040600-generic #201606100558 SMP Fri Jun 10 10:01:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

apt show libreoffice
Package: libreoffice
Version: 1:5.2.0~rc4-0ubuntu1~xenial2

apt -a show libreoffice-gtk2
Package: libreoffice-gtk2
Version: 1:5.2.0~rc4-0ubuntu1~xenial2

OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30

apt show xfce4 
Package: xfce4
Version: 4.12.2
```

[image: LO settings - Use hardware accelerationa and use anti-aliasing are set]

Comment: i just solved it by "activating use opengl for all rendering" in options,view

Comment: I have since upgraded to  Build ID: 1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2  OS Version: Linux 4.8; UI Render: default;  and this issue is resolved (both with intel and nvidea GPUs)

Comment: Hit this after updating to LibreOffice 6.0.7.3 (on Windows - google brought me here though) - same solution Tools>Options>View Use OpenGL for all rendering - worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and it was driving me crazy... one workaround that worked for me is to set the theme integration to gtk3:

```
SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk3 libreoffice --calc
```

See [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LibreOffice#Theme).

Comment: I actually updated to the latest release in the ppa, and that uses gtk3. Also tried fourcing using your command. The problem is a little better now. it refreshes and clears a bit more often. Unfortunately it isn't 100% fixed

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of banging my head against this wall, I just discovered I can solve the problem by removing the Cell freeze in my sheet.